# How to rescue URI::InvalidURIError when raised by Rack in a Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

Our Rails app sometimes receives a completely-garbled URL that causes Rack to raise `URI::InvalidURIError`.  Our exception-notification system (HoneyBadger) then receives notification of this error.

However, I don't want to know about these errors: I'd prefer that Rack just log them (if possible) and swallow them.

The app handles `ActionController::RoutingError` via this in `routes.rb`:

```
# Default route, because these would normally not go through the application rescue_from block
match('*path', to: 'application#routing_error') unless Rails.env.development?
```

... and then logging (but not notifying) when a routing error occurs in `ApplicationController#routing_error`.

But, this invalid URI error occurs prior to routes ever seeing the URL.

Here's a sample URL that causes the issue (domain name changed, of course) - `http://www.whatever.com/HD2EU]`.  And the stack trace that ensues:

```
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:176:in `split`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:994:in `URI`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.3/lib/rack/ssl.rb:50:in `redirect_to_https`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.3/lib/rack/ssl.rb:32:in `call`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.5.130/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22:in `call`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.5.130/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load`
[PROJECT_ROOT]/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>`
```

Comment: I'd also love to know this. Sometimes Google Crawler decides to crawl these badly formatted URIs and our Rails apps returns 500 errors. I wanted them to be 404s, because the URL doesn't exist, so I can reduce the number of 5xx warnings in my Google Webmasters console.

Answer (score 1):

I simply ended up adding this to the honeybadger.rb initializer:

`config.ignore << URI::InvalidURIError`